# Code server on AWS EC2 return error and doesn't start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, code-server

I follow the guide to install code-server on EC2, but it doesn't works.

When I access to my instance from browser, I have this error:

```
Error connecting to your code-server instance
Ensure code-server is running and was properly started with the --link command line flag.
```

I've tried to install code-server on EC2 manually, but it doesn't start.
At the end I've found code-server on aws marketplace (*aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-bw5rwv7u435ey*)
and follow the instruction, but at the command:

```
 systemctl status code-server
```

I've got:

```
code-server.service
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit code-server.service has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

How can I run code-server on AWS EC2?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install code-server only by install script.

```
curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh
```

Install Caddy.
It works

Don't follow the guide on gitHub, don't run launch-code-server.sh

When you will access by browser it will ask you the password. You find the password on `~/.config/code-server/config.yaml`